# How can I assign static IP address with a specific gateway in an ISC DHCP Server?

Tags: gateway, isc-dhcp

I have a router whose WAN Gateway I want to modify, without other routers in the network being affected. I want to test how the network behaves if I change the gateway for only one router.

How could I perform this inside the `/etc/dhcp/dhcp.conf` file?

Comment: 1) stateless, 2) it's not a static address, it's a DHCP reservation

Answer (score 2):

I've found the answer (not explicitly) in the documentation: http://www.isc.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/DHCP-4.3.1-Distribution-Documentation-Aug-4-14.pdf , page 22.

There we can see how parameters can be declared (not only "hardware ethernet" or "fixed-address", as we have been always been doing) and figured out that the string needed for this option to work is `option routers 10.0.0.2;`

So finally, this is the complete answer:

```
host MyClient {
        hardware ethernet d8:b6:b7:40:76:12;
        fixed-address 10.0.0.200;
        option routers 10.0.0.2;
}
```